# Is there any way to STOP the loop of the IDApython?

Tags: ida, malware, idapython, ida-plugin

Is there any way to STOP the loop of the IDApython ?
I want to stop the loop processing of IDAPython with any timing after starting the IDAPython(which contain loop function) from IDApro menu -> File -> Script command.
Is there any keyboard shortcut to stop the script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "wait box" comes up when a Python script is running for a while; you can click "cancel" to stop the script. Via keyboard, that should just be `ENTER` if that dialog has the keyboard focus.

Comment: Thank you so much. The wait box repeats show over and over, but the display is instantaneous and too fast to press. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I can stop it by pressing Enter key repeatedly, thanks.

Comment: And if you ever go on to develop your own scripts, never write `except KeyboardInterrupt: return` which will bite you one day.  :)

Now if only I could find a way to abort scripts launched from IPyIda, which is otherwise an excellent improvement on the Python console line (though it does need a few patches to fix the annoyances).